KeyCloak JWT Claim Token roles not found
While accessing APIs using keycloak as oath provider got an error as:

message": "Requires role: Library.Read"

I checked that access token on jwt.io web site found that token claim has those roles.
I am trying to integrate keyclaok with Swagger API, for that I created realm and client with required scope which was mentioned in API application. then created user and realm roles that roles attached to user. like roles is Library.Read those roles configured in swager API application and while accessing that
